# Firebase vision Face detection get tight fit estimation of the face using heuristics (MLKit)

Tags: math, computer-vision, face-detection, firebase-mlkit

On `setContourMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_CONTOURS)` face detector slows down considerably. I was wondering if we can get a tight fit face estimation using just the bounding box and initial face contour. Say at the start of the app we get a face contour as a path object on android and then during the app we just do fast face detection and use heuristics to  translate the initial path using following inputs

1. Current bounding box
2. getHeadEulerAngleY()
3. getHeadEulerAngleZ()

See the image below. The rectangle is the bounding box, oval is bounding box converted to oval, the red curve is the face contour given from the detector. 
The question is can we translate the face path of the left plot using the above inputs. This does not have to be 100% correct, close estimation is more than enough so that I don't have to sacrifice performance. I cant use bounding box because as you can see from the image, it does not fit the face well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get the tight face contour, you could enable contour, but disable all the others, like landmark and classification. Also set the mode to FAST. It should give you reasonable performance.

```
FaceDetectorOptions options = new FaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
    .setContourMode(FaceDetectorOptions.CONTOUR_MODE_ALL)
    .build());
```